# Adding atrribute to all elements with specifeid class using js

Tags: setattribute, getelementsbyclassname

```
*JS*
document.getElementsByClassName('abc')[0].setAttribute('id', 'abe');

*html*
<div class="abc"></div>
<div class="abc"></div>
```

How to make this script work with more than one element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thing like this

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('abc');
for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].setAttribute('id', 'abe');
}
```